# Font-size behaves strangely

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-size

I use font-face in CSS with some custom font.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Some font';
    src: url('Somefont.ttf');
}
html {
    font-family: 'Some font';
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

On Mac OS everything is working perfectly but on Windows the font is displayed ugly, one letter could be bigger than another. With different font-size letters are displayed differently.

Here is the print screen, the letter "r" is bigger than other letters:

[image]

I tried to fix it with different font-face options but it didn't help.

Comment: are you checking this on a real Windows machine or on Parallels or some other emulator from your Mac? I had similar things on Parallels, but on "real Windows" everything looked fine.

Comment: I don't mean if the website is real - I mean if you are viewing it on Windows hardware or on a Windows emulator on a Mac...

Comment: Yes, two different machines, one is Macbook Pro and another is Windows Desktop PC

Comment: Okay. Well, you might want to provide more font types than just a ttf font. Fontsquirrel has a Generator for these and also a tutorial here: https://www.fontspring.com/support/installing_webfonts/how-do-i-use-the-webfonts?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=help_link&utm_campaign=installing_webfonts

Comment: Here's the link to the font generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: It tried fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and it said that the font is corrupt and cannot be converted.

Comment: I just checked your website and it all looks good ... Chrome/IE/Edge, Windows 10

Comment: @LGSon try again please, I tested and deleted that font. Now I restored the font.

Comment: Still good...this time checked with Firefox/Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: Hm, I'm testing on Windows 7

Comment: Your font looks suspiciously like Helvetica. Windows is known to render Helvetica very poorly - which is why Arial exists. As much as I hate to say it, the solution is to not serve Helvetica to Windows users. (Why are you serving Helvetica as a webfont in the first place? It's unlikely you have the license to do so.)

Comment: Start by using a WOFF instead of a TTF, and make sure to include the `format()` part of the src, not just a url.